# Better switching logic for table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, optimization

Im my table view, I want to switch the accessory from a checkmark, to not having a checkmark (and back again) - I currently do it like this:

```
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

Now I know there is a better way of writing this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I see with what you've got now is that it relies on the cell to save state. The decision about whether to give a cell a check or not should probably be based not on the cell but on the data that's being displayed in the cell, like:

```
if (vehicle.selected) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

If you want to make that a little more cryptic, you could:

```
cell.accessoryType = vehicle.selected ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark
                                      : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

Some folks like that notation, others hate it. Check your local coding standards document to find out whether such code is acceptable before using.